# C++ detail namespace vs anonymous vs private method to class vs. pimpl vs. friend class

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend-class

Bear with me here. 
I am trying to figure out at what point do you draw the line regarding putting helper methods in anon vs. detail namespace vs. private vs. creating pimpl or friend class.

Here's my take.. Please let me know your thoughts.

So, if I have 
  foo.hpp 
  foo.cpp

and I have some free function `bar` that do not access any data members in `foo`, and furthermore no clients need to know those free functions and only `foo.cpp`'s method need them just directly put them in anon namespace in foo.cpp and be done with it.

If however, `bar` needs access to foo's data members we can make `bar` private method of foo. But that means that even though foo's client don't really care about `bar`, everytime `bar` changes, we have a recompilation.

(This part I am a bit fuzzy):
However, atleast using a detail namespace in this case, helps readers of foo.hpp not to bother looking at `bar`, since they really don't need to know it.  Is this the general usecase for detail namespace convention?

Now, if we have bunch of bar_1, bar_2...bar_n and they kind of relate together and they need access to data members , I can make a friend class `baz` to foo , and put the `bar`s there.

If however, I am really concerned about compilation time and hiding the interface i can resort to pimpl (again very fuzzy on this part, usually if I see this, alarm bell goes off and tells me something is off in the design).

Your thoughts...

Comment: Don't describe code in English, post code.

Comment: ***Your thoughts*** I would go ahead and use PIMPL. https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/

Answer (score 5):

As someone commented earlier, it would be better to provide an example of code with your question as the concepts you are describing are pretty abstract and complex.

Here is my take on the items you want to know more about: Private methods, Private implementation, Unnamed namespace non-member function, non-member function in a "named" namespace and friend non-member function.

**Private Methods**: First you will have to declare those in your class declaration so their prototype will be publicly visible even if nobody outside of your class can call it. This is a little non-sensical. You should use those methods in 2 kind of situations:

1. You need to access something that is private to your class in the implementation of this method.
2. You are implementing a virtual method using the NVI idiom.

**Private Implementation**: You should use this to hide the implementation details of your class. AKA its data members. One thing I do often is to forward declare my pImpl type in my class header file and make my class friend of the private implementation class in the cpp file.

**Unnamed namespace non-member function**: These are more or less equivalent to non-member functions declared with the static keyword in your implementation file. You should shoot for those as much as possible. A good rule of thumb is that all non-virtual private methods should be implementable as non-friend, non-member functions declared un the unnamed namespace. This has the advantage that it forces you to use the public interface of your class in the implementation of such functions. One important warning: Never ever use the unnamed namespace in a header file. (.h or .hpp) If you do, every prototype in those files will have a unique symbol each time that file in included. This can rapidly result in a symbol mess.

**Non-member non-friend function within a namespace**: Most of the time, you will use these functions when you want to add services to your class or provide helper functions that are not bound to a class. The advantage of these functions is that they use only the public interface of your classes. One good example of a good usage of these methods is when you implement operators for your class. 
Let's say you have class "A" and class "B". and you want to add an instance of A to an instance of B. The transitivity rule says that you could also add B to A with the same result. If you make the operator+ non member, you don't have to modify either classes to implement this feature. If you do it as a public method you will have to do it in both classes. I would recommend you Scott Meyers "Effective C++" if you want to know more on that subject.

**Friend non-member functions**: You should avoid these as much as possible. The reason being that their implementation rely on private details of your class. Why else would you have made them friend? It is accepted that the private implementation details of a class can change at any time which may break your function or worse: Make it behave in a different way than intended.

So there you have it, use the private method when you have virtual methods to declare through the NVI idiom, put your data members in Private implementations, declare all your non-virtual private methods in your implementation file under the unnamed namespace, declare public services as non-member non-friend functions as much as possible and do not use any friend non-member functions.

Comment: Due to the abstractness of the question, I found it hard to provide code sample. I was trying to figure out the different scenarios, where one design triumps on the other. This was nicely put down and shows the different use cases succinctly. Trying to find more detailed information. Does the following capture your thoughts.. ? `Non-member non-friend function`.. : `Scott Meyers: How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation` ,  For Private Implementation, PIMPL ` Herb Sutter: What's In a Class? - The Interface Principle`

Comment: For Non-member non-friend function: I was referring to Scott Meyers: Effective C++ Third Edition - Item 23: "Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions." As for the pImpl, I simply gave my take on the matter. There are a lots of schools of thoughts around the pImpl, but this is what experience and time taught me was the best approach to it. What I have explained here is what I teach to our junior developers to do and it seems to be working quite well for them. I really hope it will do the same for you.